# Target attribute in li link?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following link, but it is always opening in the same page. I want it to open in a new page. I looked already some tutorials, but cannot find an answer to my question.

I would like to implement this directly to the link, not the page. Because I have other links, and they need to go in the same page

my code:

```
    if( $text1 ) {
      echo '<li class="social-icons FB"><a href='.$text1.' '.$target.' data-tip="Facebook"><img width='.$imgW.'  height='.$imgh.' src='.plugins_url( '/images/'. $imgtype .'facebook.png').'></a></li>';
   }
```

Can somebody help me with correct code?

Comment: Can you show the values of $text1 and $target?

Comment: Is this sufficiant?

$targetlinks = get_option('targetlinks'); 
 if($targetlinks =='1'){ $target = 'target="_blank"';}else{$target='';}

Comment: is $text1 a string? You want to check if it is not empty? Use `if(!empty($text1) {`. Also what is the value of $targetlinks in your page?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Don't you just need the target attribute, like so: ...<a href='.$text1.' target= '.$target.' data-tip="Facebook">....'

Comment: I see that it's looking for an option (one that I've set in the options pane) to open in new tab.

But it's not working. So I like to overrule in the code

Can i set this to something like?

$targetlinks = {target="_blank"}

Comment: Check the generated sourcecode in your browser. You will notice that your target property is missing the `target=` part.

Comment: Also ... in your code, did you mean: `$target = 'target="_blank"'` ? If so, please take a bit more time to learn about PHP, variable assignments and other basic tutorials.

Comment: Huh, sorry i'm not a coder, i'm trying to change a plugin that is not working as it supposed to.

I know the target property is missing, because it's a general property

sorry guys i'm doing my best.

Both the code's are here. You have the Li code in my post. And the $target in my first answer.

and yes the $text is filled in, otherwise it wouldn't show the icon in my widget area. It is opening the correct page, but not in the correct window.

Comment: ToBe that answer is just lame. I'm learning PHP and the reason this site exist is to get help. So I'm using it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

add below code after href..

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: I've tried that allready but that don't work because it's in conflict with the $Targetlinks